# ReactJS post request not sending values to Django backend

Tags: reactjs, django

I have a React frontend component that is for Login/Account creation. The problem I'm facing is that when trying to register a new user I am getting a Bad Request error. After printing the request on the backend I see the request as `<WSGIRequest: POST '/register/'>`

Here's my react function:

```
const handleRegister = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/register/", {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      setMessage(data.success || data.error);
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage("An error occurred. Please try again.");
    }
  };
```

And here's my Django function:

```
def register(request):
    print(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        if not username or not password:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Missing username or password'}, status=400)

        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return JsonResponse({'success': 'User registered and logged in'})
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)}, status=400)

    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method'}, status=405)
```

This is my request payload from the browser:

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "body": "{\"username\":\"test\",\"password\":\"test\"}"
}
```

Response:
`{"error": "Missing username or password"}`

Not sure what I'm missing to make it so the values are lost between frontend to backend..

I've switched to axios from fetch to see if that was my issue. I've installed/enabled CORS in the Settings.py

Comment: This seems to be due to some issue in the view. If I attempt this request from postman I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you're sending a combined object in the place of body

```
 const handleRegister = async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          try {
            const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/register/", {
              username,
              password
            }, {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
              },
              withCredentials: true
            });
        
            const data = response.data;
            setMessage(data.success || data.error);
          } catch (error) {
            setMessage("An error occurred. Please try again.");
          }
        };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Django 4 here.
To accept JSON data in Django, there are a few things you need to tweak in your code.

First, as mentioned by Ruzaik Nazeer, you are combining settings from axios with your post data in your request. The correct format to call an API using `axios.post` is as follows:

```
axios.post(url, data, axiosConfiguration)
```

You can refer to the official axios documentation for more details and examples: [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example)

To make the request work as you want it to, we need to adjust your code as follows:

```js
const handleRegister = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const response = await axios.post(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/",
    {
      username,
      password,
    },
    {
      mode: "cors",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    }
  );
};
```

Note that when using `"Content-Type": "application/json"`, you can't access your data via `request.POST` in django. Instead, you need to use `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` as the header.

The `headers` object in the `axios.post` request now includes the `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` header. This allows you to access the data on the server-side via `request.POST.get('username')`, for example.

The Django code on the server-side can stay the same.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the axios call. Unfortunately these changes have the same isue.

Comment: Maybe try to use `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt` as decorator on your view.